# Calendar with DatePicker always returns last month even if I add + 1

Tags: java, android, datepicker, calendar

I was trying to get Year-Month-Day from Calendar object, I know month start from index of 0. So I added +1 to month object. But still it gives me the last month from selection through date picker.

Where I am going wrong?

This is how I am trying.

This is my fragmentActivity

```
public class MyDatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
        int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        DatePickerDialog myDatePicker =
                new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
        return myDatePicker;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day) {
        EditText et = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editTextDate1);
        et.setText(year+"-"+month+"-"+day);
    }

}
```

This is my MainActivity

```
EditText ed2;
ed2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextDate2);
ed2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                DialogFragment myDatePickerFragment = new MyDatePickerFragmentTo();
                myDatePickerFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"datePicker");
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`onDateSet()` gets called with zero-based month as mentioned in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener.html):

> `monthOfYear` The month that was set (0-11) for compatibility with `Calendar`.

You need to adjust the month value there, too.